# How to pivot dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark 2.1.

I have some data in a Spark Dataframe, which looks like below:

```
**ID** **type** **val** 
  1       t1       v1      
  1       t11      v11
  2       t2       v2
```

I want to pivot up this data using either spark Scala (preferably) or Spark SQL so that final output should look like below:

```
**ID**   **t1**   **t11**   **t2**
  1        v1       v11
  2                            v2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupBy.pivot`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.first
df.groupBy("ID").pivot("type").agg(first($"val")).na.fill("").show
+---+---+---+---+
| ID| t1|t11| t2|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1| v1|v11|   |
|  2|   |   | v2|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Note: depending on the actual data, i.e. how many values there are for each combination of `ID` and `type`, you might choose a different aggregation function.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "T1", "v1"),
  (1, "T11", "v11"),
  (2, "T2", "v2")
).toDF(
  "id", "type", "val"
).as[(Int, String, String)]

val df2 = df.groupBy("id").pivot("type").agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list("val")))

df2.show
+---+---+---+---+
| id| T1|T11| T2|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1| v1|v11|   |
|  2|   |   | v2|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Note that if there are different `val`s associated with a given `type`, they will be grouped (comma-delimited) under the `type` in `df2`.

Answer (score 1):

This one should work

```
val seq = Seq((123,"2016-01-01","1"),(123,"2016-01-02","2"),(123,"2016-01-03","3"))
val seq = Seq((1,"t1","v1"),(1,"t11","v11"),(2,"t2","v2"))     
val df = seq.toDF("id","type","val")
val pivotedDF = df.groupBy("id").pivot("type").agg(first("val"))
pivotedDF.show
```

Output:

```
+---+----+----+----+
| id|  t1| t11|  t2|
+---+----+----+----+
|  1|  v1| v11|null|
|  2|null|null|  v2|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Comment: well you should consider answer from "Psidom" as its taking care of nulls [ as per requirement]

Comment: i am getting this error:error: not found: value first

Comment: what version of spark you are on?

Comment: I am using  spark 2.1